# How to access calendar in MacOS screensaver?

Tags: swift, macos, privacy, macos-big-sur, screensaver

Is it possible to access calendar events in screen saver? I am able to request permission in the application. But some API is not prompting in the case of the screensaver.

I didn't find any documentation around it.

I used the following code to requesting calendar events:

```
func requestPermissionForCalendar()
{
    var eventStore = EKEventStore()
    
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event) { granted, error in
        
        if granted{
            print("Permission granted")
        }else{
            print("The app is not permitted to access reminders, make sure to grant permission in the settings and try again")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't screenserver just a window with a high level (NSWindowLevel kCGScreenSaverWindowLevel = 1000)? So the prompt is hidden behind?

Comment: yeah, that might be the case, no way to debug to find out the exact view hierarchy. tried with 0.1 opacity and clear color background. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, first, a screen saver is completely passive in macOS. Any prompt for anything will be disregarded when it's running fullscreen, as a screensaver.

In general, the proper way to do this with a screensaver is to ask for permission in the configurationSheet (the screen saver options). The user will get prompted there, and can allow or deny you. I do use this for example to request the user location.

Once allowed in System Preferences, your screensaver when running in screensaver mode will get access. I suggest you test your code first in the configuration sheet as this is much easier.

Additional note, ScreenSavers on macOS since Catalina are sandboxed by an application extension provided by Apple, and that extension has a limited list of entitlements (see a list here https://github.com/glouel/ScreenSaverMinimal).

I'm not particularly familiar with EKEventStore, but if it requires a specific entitlement to make it work, you'll be stuck as you can't add any entitlement yourself, everything depends on `legacyScreenSaver.appex`.